# convert from string to nText in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, ado.net

I can not insert data to database because it is different data type between the parameter and field in data base.

How to convert string in controller to nText in database?

Comment: Make sure your parameter's type matches the field's type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on your store procedure's or query's parameters. If you define your parameter correctly, it will get the right value.

Comment: So what is the possible data type of parameter should I define?

Comment: :) because I just a beginner of asp.net . sorry for inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

If your proc takes ntext this is mappable to a .net string as its a unicode string. Beyond that we need more details (your .net code, your proc code, the error)